# What is the mechanism of using param 'scale_pos_weight' in xgboost?

Tags: xgboost

My dataset has 90% negative samples and 10% positive samples which is very imbalanced. I try to use the parameter of scale_pos_weight and set it as 9. What is the mechanism of this param do. I am curious about what it actually means: does it mean repeat the positive samples 9 times? Or everytime pull out 1/9 samples of negative samples and train the model in many times. besides, if I have a dataset whose negative samples just a little more than the positive ones, should I need to specify the parameter again?

Answer (score 1):

`scale_pos_weight` in xgboost is just used to multiply the weights as [is source code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/src/objective/regression_obj.cu#L86). There is no subsampling done based on this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen anywhere in the documentation that states explicitly what this parameter does. However, I am quite confident that it is the latter, i.e. it builds trees based on 1/9th of the negative samples. Although both should have approximately the same effect if the data are good, taking a subset of the negatives is the convention for modeling because it allows for easier cross-validation, since you now have 9 training sets that you can check against each other.

As a side note, I wouldn't necessarily assume that a 90/10 split is so unbalanced. That's a lot better than you'll get in many situations, and there's some [debate](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/02/does-balancing-classes-improve-classifier-performance/) over whether re-balancing is always helpful.